# Is there a database agnostic way to execute a stored procedure with params

Tags: entity-framework-core

Using Entity Framework Core 2.1 I have code that calls a stored procedure, passing in some params. During execution we are using Sql Server and everything works as expected. Our test cases however, run using Sqlite. Is there a decent way (without overly polluting the code with unwanted code added only to support testing) to get the code to run regardless of which database is actually being used?

Currently the code in question looks like this:

```
await MyContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("UpdateEndDate @p0, @p1, @p2", id, from, thru);
```

And causes a SqliteException:

```
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=SQLite Error 1: 'near "UpdateEndDate": syntax error'.
  Source=Microsoft.Data.Sqlite
  ...
```

(Also wondering why are there SqlParameter and SQLiteParameter? Why cant there be a database agnostic parameter class?)

Configuration for DBContext in test harness is below:

```
public static SqliteConnection GetConnection()
{
    SqliteConnection connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
    connection.Open();

    connection.CreateFunction(
    "NEWID",
    Guid.NewGuid(),
    g => g);

    return connection;
}

serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
    .<snipped>
    .AddEntityFrameworkSqlite()
    .AddDbContext<MyContext>(
    (theServiceProvider, opt) => opt
    .UseInternalServiceProvider(theServiceProvider)
    .UseSqlite(GetConnection()))
    .BuildServiceProvider();

MyContext cc = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(MyContext)) as MyContext;
cc.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

Comment: because DBContext represents the specific database. Its by design

Comment: I dont think so. That's why you set the database provider in DbContextOptions not the DbContext. See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/sqlite. You can obviously write code that only works with a specific provider as I have done above - but in thousands of lines of codes this is the first time I have done so (and the code in question is not in the DbContext!)

Comment: yes but again DBConextOptions is being used for DBContext only

Comment: Right, at any given time the DbContext is connected to a specific  database - but the design is supposed to be that in most cases you can write code that will work regardless of which database that ends up being. The question is what mechanism have they provided to do this when you need to pass a param to a procedure.

Comment: I think you should pass the DBContext in parameter wherever you are writing this logic.

Comment: are you using SQLite provider for in memory testing? if so another option is the InMemory provider.

Comment: also, can you show us the instantiation/configuration of MyContext?

Comment: I forget exactly why at the moment but early on decided InMemory provider wasnt capable enough to support my  needs.

Comment: Configuration I don't think matters but added to original question

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the DbProviderFactory class? It became available in Core 2.1. Put both connection strings in your appSettings.json and in the startup set appropriate DbContext based on the environment it's running in.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbproviderfactory?view=netcore-2.1